# Hash-Based Sharding in MongoDB

Tags: c#, sql-server, node.js, mongodb, 10gen-csharp-driver

I am trying to set up hash-based sharding, but it doesn't works. I am using mongo 2.4.

It would be great to see real examples of how to start mongo claster. (steps)

How to configure hash-based sharding for large MongoDB deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's  [Hash-Based Sharing example](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/47633823714/new-hash-based-sharding-feature-in-mongodb-2-4) from MongoDB blog...